# Formula to calculate difference between two dates

Tags: soft-question

I am working on getting date difference I have a formula to calculate it as follows

$$365\cdot\mathrm{year} + \frac{\mathrm{year}}4 - \frac{\mathrm{year}}{100} + \frac{\mathrm{year}}{400} + \mathrm{date} + \frac{153\cdot \mathrm{month}+8}5$$

but its not working on leap years like

if dates are 1-1-2012 and 1-1-2013 the difference should be 366 days but its giving 365.

where am I wrong?

Comment: Where did you get the $153$ multiplied by the months?

Comment: I got the formula on internet.

Comment: it is used to cover up the differences occurred due to `year/4−year/100+year/400`.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/683325/formula-to-calculate-difference-between-tow-dates

Comment: I give a formula for getting the day number from a date and an algorithm for getting the date from a day number in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/473911)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem has been addressed six weeks ago on this site. I give you the link to the post and answers.

[Subtracting two dates](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/630476/subtracting-two-dates/630499#630499)

It is not a trivial problem at all (in particular because of the leap years) and I think that the easiest way to solve it is to go through Julian day numbers and perform substraction. Programming this is quite simple (if you need a piece of code, I could make one for you).

**Added later**

Searching in my notes, I found something (I do not remember where in the Internet) that I put between quotes (I put in bold what I think important) :

> "First of all, since February is an especially short month, it is
>   normally better to consider January and February the 13th and 14th
>   months of the previous year.  So first, **if the month is 1 or 2**, then
>   you **add 12 to the month** and **subtract 1 from the year**.  Then the day
>   is
>
> 365*year + year/4 - year/100 + year/400 + date + (153*month+8)/5
>
> where all of the divisions are **rounded DOWN** to the nearest integer
>   .
>
> Do this for both dates, and subtract."

Do not forget to **use the floor of the result of any division**.

Comment: Still the same problem :(

Comment: @eatSleepCode. So, you made a mistake : $01-01-2012$ must be treated as $01-13-2011$ and  $01-01-2013$ must be treated as $01-13-2012$; the results are $734902$ and $735268$ which differ by $366$. Give a lot of attention to what robjohn gave in a previous post.

Answer (score 2):

Use this formula :

First convert both the dates to number of days

Before using the below formula - use these calculations

- If Month <= 2, then subtract 1 from Year ( if mm <=2 then Year = Year - 1  else Year = Year)
- If Month <= 2, then add 13 to month or add 1 to month ( if mm <=2 then mm = mm+13 else mm = mm+1)

Number of Days = ${(1461 * Year)\over4} + {(153 * Month)\over5} + Day $

Using the above formula, you will have the number of days.

Now do the same for the same for the second date.

Then Difference = Days2 - Days1 will give you the difference between 2 dates.

Answer (score 0):

```
if m <=2
then m = m+12,
     y = y-1

no_of_days = (146097*y)/400 + (153*m + 8)/5 + d
```

Do this for both dates and then subtract.After subtracting you will get the number of days between two dates (excluding the end date)

Comment: From where did you get these numbers ?

Comment: This is one day off for many dates. For example in R this prints 0 instead of 1: `dai=\(y,m,d){b=m<=2;(146097*ifelse(b,y-1,y))%/%400+(153*ifelse(b,m+12,m)+8)%/%5+d};dai(2008,3,1)-dai(2008,2,29)`.